# spacy matcher pattern IN + REGEX Tag

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk, spacy

My goal is to match with spacy the sentences that contain one of the following words:
['studium','abschluss','ausbildung']

I can solve the problem with this line:

```
pattern = [{"LOWER": {'IN':['studium','abschluss', 'ausbildung']}}]
```

My problem is that in German there is a vast use of composed words like Hochschulstudium, Masterstudium, Studiengang etc.

How can use the regex inside the IN sentence to match all words containing the word Studium?

Comment: `pattern = [{'LOWER': {'REGEX':r'^[^\W\d_]*studium$'}}]`?

Comment: Or do you mean you want to use some list as a variable inside the regex that will match either `abschluss`, `ausbildun` or any word ending with `studium`?

Comment: Can I add to this pattern also the words abschluss and ausbildung?

Comment: Not only ending, It would be nice to match all the words that contains the word "Studium"

Comment: I noticed that some job offers offer gym membership, so I also added a negation to your pattern:  `pattern = [{'LOWER': {'REGEX':fr'^(?:{"|".join(map(re.escape, l))}|(?!fitness)[^\W\d_]*studi)[^\W\d_]*$'}}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `REGEX` operator:

```py
import re
l = ['abschluss', 'ausbildung']
pattern = [{'LOWER': {'REGEX':fr'^(?:{"|".join(map(re.escape, l))}|[^\W\d_]*studium)$'}}]
```

Note:

- `map(re.escape, l)` - escapes the items in the `l` list
- `"|".join(...)` - joins the words as alternatives (`word1|word2|wordN`)
- `^(?:...|[^\W\d_]*studium)$` - a regex that matches

  - `^` - start of string (here, token)
  - `(?:...|[^\W\d_]*studium)` - a non-capturing group matching any of the `l` items or any zero or more letters (`[^\W\d_]*`) followed with `studium`
  - `$` - end of string (token here).

Comment: I can modify your line to add also words that starts with "studium"

Comment: @SalvaHH If it just can contain `studium`, use `[^\W\d_]*studium[^\W\d_]*` instead of `[^\W\d_]*studium`.

Comment: Yes I did it already, many thanks!